# What is use of 'this' in react component

Tags: reactjs

Thank you for contributing your precious time

**I am a beginner to react.js;** 
The word this gets used in React a lot!

I couldn't figure out, what is the use of 'this' in react component.

I read a few articles but, clarity of concept in my mind didn't well

Why did we need to write 'this'?

```
class MyName extends React.Component {
  get name() {
    return 'akash';
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>My name is {this.name}.</h1>;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is actually a javascript concept. try to explore javascript first.

Comment: @mehta-rohan I did that, I am just little confused with new syntax and other new things

Comment: ok, keep working on it, best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` refers to your component/class itself. In other languages you can compare it to `self`. This is to specify that the variable/function you're trying to access or trying to modify is owned by a class so that when you have a parameter with same name with your class variable, the compiler can identify which one was owned by your class.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `this` is your MyComponent class. So if you do `this.name` you will access to your `name` function that returns an string

If you are learning react, I will recommend you check his official tutorial https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: I got it but what is the purpose behind writing 'this'?

Comment: because you are invoking a function, and to call a function you need to specify where that function is, in your case that functions is in your Class